# Is there a way to split sql information after a full stop in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, split

I am pulling a lot of information from 1 cell in a database for example.  This is a silly. big and amazing. sentence of awesomeness.

Is there a way that i can split the read in php so it comes out in a new line for every full stop.

```
<?php 

    $query = "SELECT * from testview";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row s =$res->num_rows;
    $i = 1;
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
<?php echo $result['QuestionText'];?>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to split the echo

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you wanting to do? Do you have an example of coding where you are trying to do what you want?

Comment: Does this make more sense

Comment: Sure you can split but what is a "full stop". Can you post an example of the data? "Sentences of awesomeness" doesn't necessarily help us understand what you're dealing with. Maybe you're looking for: `<?php echo $result['QuestionText']."<br>\n";?>`

Comment: Do you mean you want each QuestionText to be on it's own line?

Comment: Okay none of these An example of the data is 
"Hello welcome to my supercool website. do you have any time to play a game. no well okay thanks for coming anyway." I want this split onto 3 different lines

Comment: `explode()` on the period.

Comment: You could simply replace the `.` with `.<br>` (or `.\n` if you are into plain text stuff), like this: `str_replace('.','.<br>',$result['QuestionText']);`

Comment: @AlexSzabó Using both `<br>` and `\n` would be better, and will produce cleaner HTML with `\n`. ;-) instead off all in one big clump on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your examples, lets say

```
$result['QuestionText'] = "Hello welcome to my supercool website. do you have any time to play a game. no well okay thanks for coming anyway.";
```

And you want to split this up onto different line by sentence.

Quick way is to replace the periods with a `<br>\n`

```
echo str_replace('.', '.<br/>\n', $result['QuestionText']);
```

A more desirable way (IMO) would be to split the text into an array by the periods.

```
$aryQText = explode('.', $result['QuestionText']);
```

Now `$aryQText` is an array with three elements, each is a sentence from your text. Then you can just loop through the element like so.

```
foreach($aryQText as $sentence){
  echo "$sentence.<br/>\n";
}
```

This way is much more flexible.

Comment: How would i call each array element in php ? for example that would explode it into 3 sections

Comment: Use either `foreach` or `implode`, but the later would kind of defeat the purpose of that solution. ;)

Comment: One last question @dan08 is there a way to change the format between each foreach loop thanks

Comment: Yes, `$sentence` is just a string that you can do anything with. Thats why I say that way is more flexible.